# Alternatives to Kruskal-Wallis or one way Anova test for small size samples

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, hypothesis-testing

I have a group of measurements 'grouped by year' and on each year I have only one recorded measure, such as the example below:

```
measure           | group 

0.918013116736037 |2008
0.87700851127606  |2009
0.865305712564198 |2010
0.885404924545329 |2011
0.91228191516954  |2012
0.868529155787641 |2013
0.844761039845612 |2014
0.892400123529577 |2015
```

I want to use a statistical test to say wether there is a 'significant' different between these measures or not.. I know that I can use anova or Kruskal-Wallis test for such problems but due to the small size of samples per groups I don't think it will be sufficient !

I also cannot generate more data as the measures that I am using are actually a classification accuracy on the data collected on each group 'each year' ! which mean repeating the classification on the same sample will be like cheating !

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do any meaningful hypothesis test to see if years
are significantly different with only one observation per year.
You would need some way to judge whether variability among
years is surprisingly large compared to variability within years.
But with only one observation per year, you have no way to
estimate variability within years. (To put it another way,
there is no such thing as "groups" of size 1 in such tests.)

Instead, I suggest you focus on the variability among years
in a a few different ways.

First, you might look at the
standard deviation of the yearly measurements. It is roughly 0.02.
Knowing what you do about these measurements and what they
mean, do you think this is a large or small amount of 
variability? (The mean of your data is about 0.88, Roughly
speaking, there should be few instances in which any one year
is beyond three standard deviations of the mean in either direction:
$0.88 \pm 0.06.$ Does that seem reasonable based on what
you know about these measurements?)

Second, I rounded your observations to three places (for convenience)
and made a boxplot of them--including the usual feature of
boxplots that notes outliers. There are no outliers here.

[image]

Third, I also plotted your observations in sequence. There is no clear
trend of decrease or increase across the years for which you
have data. (With so few observations, it is very dangerous to
speculate about cycles, but there may be a *hint* of
down-up-down-up cycles in your data. With more years of data you might eventually
be in a better position to look for meaningful cycles.)

[image]

Note: If it is possible to go back to the original data and find
*monthly* (or *quarterly*) accuracy scores. Then you would have
12 (or 4) observations per year and you could do a Kruskal-Wallis
or some other test to see if there is a significant difference
from year to year.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, I can actually go back to the data and break them down to quarters, but would this be acceptable ? I mean because every quarter will represent only part of the 'year' data , and its not like I am doing another experiment with samples belongs to the whole year ? can I group them at the end to 'yearly' groups ?

Comment: ** Update ** actually it doesn't seem I can break them down into quarters as for some quarters I don't have any data ... would 6 months period (2 inserts per year) would be acceptable ? and I could use after that Freidman test as I have multiple blocks each with ( 2 inserts per year).

Comment: Friedman test could be done. Issue is whether it would have useful power. Don't know how much work is involved in dis-aggregating the data into first and last halves of each year. Might worth a try. Also, if there are only _few_ qtrs missing maybe a general linear model ANOVA with missing data would work. (That would assume data not far from normal.) Difficult to do statistical consulting without seeing data, knowing quality of data, or knowing the objectives of your study.